# logrotate broke apache custom logging

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04, logrotate

A couple of days ago I set up logrotation for the custom set access and error logs on my system. But for some reason logging stopped all together and I can't figure out why.

Virtualhost -screenshot
https://box.jakupovic.org/public.php?service=files&t=af0096f36c5c61f18a235f31a15249c3

/etc/logrotate.d/apache2 -screenshot
https://box.jakupovic.org/public.php?service=files&t=72b20565895200cb215c2d4368bb243f

The websiteFolder is owned by root:adm and has rwx-r-xr-x permissions.

The thing is that the logrotation has occurred but no new data is written to the newly created access.log
What could cause this? What should I be looking for? I'm rather new with system administration and am still learning.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Apache usually runs as an unprivileged process, usually with user ID `apache` (Red Hat like systems) or `www-data` (Debian like systems). That user should have write access on the `websiteFolder/logs` directory.